# Не работает кодировка utf-8

Tags: php, кодировка, google-chrome, utf-8

[image: В мозилле корректно][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: lang]
С php знаком мало, но пригодился в работе.
При просмотре запроса весь текст на русском языке выдает эту кашу. Английский текст без проблем.preview[[image: headers] Сделано в OpenServer, где кодировка по умолчанию **utf-8**. Так же **Sublime** настроен на **utf-8**. В **Mozilla** отображается нормально. **Проблема только в Chrome.**
В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в кодировке ответа, скорее всего кодировка ответа с вашего сервера не `UTF-8` И по этому браузер не верно интерпретирует русские символы, на сервере в самом начале кода пропишите функцию `header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;");` это если вы выводите в браузер простой текст или если вы выводите `HTML` Код, измените заголовок в функции, уточнив что там будет `HTML` — `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;");`. Для других форматов соответсвенно, надо будет изменять `Content-Type`. Замечу, функция должна быть до любого вывода данных в браузер, иначе прийдется использовать буферизацию.

Comment: <?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;");
//читать json файл
$json = file_get_contents( '../goods.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$message = '';
$message .= '<h1>Заказ в магазине</h1>';
$message .='<p>Телефон:  '.$_POST['ephone'].'</p>';
$message .='<p>Почта:  '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
$message .='<p>Клиент:  '.$_POST['ename'].'</p>';


$cart = $_POST['cart'];

foreach ($cart as $id=>$count) {
  $message .=$json[$id]['name'].' --- ';
  $message .=$count.' --- ';
  $message .=$count*$json[$id]['cost'];
  $message .='<br>';
}
print_r($message);

Comment: Извиняюсь, скину здесь пример https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/PeWRVJ?editors=1010  Вы имели ввиду так?

Comment: Да, так. Для языков программирования, кстати, есть сервис pastebin.com.

Comment: Не работает https://pp.userapi.com/c824203/v824203929/12e6d4/XuVTYq3lzgs.jpg

Comment: Отправьте скриншот заголовков ответа от сервера с той-же вкладки в браузере.

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c847122/v847122929/38e16/Gaa79lSgwNc.jpg вот, пожалуйста

Comment: Кстати, двойным кликом открыл mail.php и текст отобразился нормально https://pp.userapi.com/c847122/v847122929/38e20/ORLAIdGKJBw.jpg

Comment: Может дело в кодировки самого файла?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Но на всякий случай скажу, что в самом html кодировка как обычно utf-8 прописана

Comment: А сам текст который вы отдаёте у вас в нормальном состоянии?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? p.s. открыл в мозилле, там отображается по - русски. Даже удалил строку, которую вы посоветовал - все равно по русски отображается

Comment: А в хроме каракули, так?

Comment: Да , в хроме каракули , в мозилее все ок.

Comment: в sublime все сделано на кодировке utf-8 + сам сервер запущен с openServer , а там по умолчанию utf-8

Comment: Сравните все заголовки запросов и ответов в хрома и мозиле, скажите если есть разница.

Comment: https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840632/v840632477/7ab23/emPfyMDCdqg.jpg     /     https://sun9-7.userapi.com/c840632/v840632477/7ab2c/h3bs-jB99l8.jpg        Разница незначительна